# Getting values of a stdObject in php

Tags: php, api, stdclass

I am using an API to get some values. When I print my variable returning an array from api it returns `stdObject Class`

This is how I request the data:

```
$graphObject = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,tagged_places' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

This is how I am printing it:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

This is what it returns:

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 111111
    [first_name] => Bob
    [last_name] => Stevensen
    [tagged_places] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 111111
                            [created_time] => 1905-01-01T08:00:00+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [latitude] => 36.1313
                                            [longitude] => -95.9373
                                        )

                                    [name] => Tulsa, Oklahoma
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 11111
                            [created_time] => 2014-05-30T21:41:11+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 111111
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [city] => Okmulgee
                                            [country] => United States
                                            [latitude] => 35.623012460758
                                            [longitude] => -95.972782756346
                                            [state] => OK
                                            [street] => 104 S Morton Ave
                                            [zip] => 74447-5022
                                        )

                                    [name] => Ike's Downtown Pub & Eatery
                                )

                        )
```

I have found some examples of this stating the way to get a value out of this class object would be like this,

```
echo $graphObject->{'$STDCLASS'}->{'$FIELD I'M TRYING TO GET'};
```

I am swapping out these values trying to figure out what the object name is but I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /file/path
```

What is the correct way to get the values from this `stdClass Object` I think maybe I am just not understanding the name of the `Object` Is it possible to tell from the code I have posted here?

Comment: you dont call it by literal 'stdClass', `$graphObject[0]->id` to access it

Comment: In terms of retrieving data, an object is just like an array except you need to use `$object->value` instead of `$object['value']`.  What data are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I want to save each one of the values in to a DB. So in this case id created time place etc

Comment: So your saying something like this... `echo $graphObject->created_time;`

Comment: it depends, if `graphObject` has may items, then you need to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

the object contains an array called Data you can access:

```
foreach ($graphObject->data as $data) {
    echo $data->id
}
```

This takes the object and should make it directly accessible

though on second thought .. you may also need to try echo $data['id']; as its not an object any more..

If that doenst work .. try :

```
$info = json_decode($graphObject,true);
```

and see if you can work the $info variable easier.

Comment: Tried to get it both ways and the first way and 2nd way I get these Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home4/originl0/public_html/sandbox/includes/header.php on line 173

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home4/originl0/public_html/sandbox/includes/header.php on line 173